# Trying to edit specific sections of huge dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

First off, new here, so let me know if I get anything wrong with posting protocol etc and I'll do my best to fix it!

**I have a very large dataset (15 cols x 1,000,000 rows) and I am trying to iterate through it to edit large groups of numbers.** Specifically, every time one column changes values, I want to reset the values of the other columns to restart their own counts from 0. To use an example, I want to take the value from data[1000][10] and subtract it from the values from data[1000:2000][10], and then do the same for data[2000][10], data[2000:3000][10] etc. However, the code I've written is either too slow, or not working correctly.

---

Things I've tried so far:
1st) I tried to use a for loop to iterate through each cell in pandas, as I'm very new to it. The code was very slow (it would take a month to run on a small file). I was later told you can't use for loops in pandas for this very reason.

E.g.

```
    for ind in range(len(data.index)-1):
        data.loc[ind, 10] = data['Charge_Capacity'][ind] - cCap
```

2nd) I tried using a combination of apply() and iloc(). I haven't seen this done elsewhere, which is probably why it isn't working, but hopefully it will demonstrate what I was attempting to achieve. The code runs but nothing changes in the output file, as far as I can tell.

```
    for ind in range(len(data.index)-1): 
        if data['Step_Index'][ind+1] != data['Step_Index'][ind]:
            resetPoints.append((ind, data['Step_Index'][ind], data['Charge_Capacity'][ind])
    for point in resetPoints:
        data.iloc[point[0]:, 5].apply(lambda x: x + 1)
        data.iloc[point[0]:, 10].apply(lambda x: x - point[2])
```

Other Notes:

- cCap above refers to the value I want to subtract from the others (e.g. data[2000][10] in the example above)
- I know I might have made an off-by-one error or two using iloc, but I don't see ANY differences in the output file and the input file, so I think the error is more than that.
- I can't group the file by Step_Index, since it sometimes loops on itself E.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 1, (etc).
- I want to select the points between two reset points (resetpoint:resetpoint2) but haven't gotten that far since the code is already failing with (resetpoint:)

I've included a cut-down version of my code so you can get a better sense of what I have so far.

'''

```
import pandas 
#Read in file as a dataframe in pandas
data = pandas.read_csv("C:/Users/ebagr/Downloads/xIris_0000B4_000001_CH17.csv")

resetPoints = []

#Cycle through the pandas dataframe
for ind in range(len(data.index)-1): 
    #Find spots where the step number changes, which might be reset points
    t1 = perf_counter()
    if data['Step_Index'][ind+1] != data['Step_Index'][ind]:
        resetPoints.append((ind, data['Step_Index'][ind], data['Charge_Capacity'][ind], data['Discharge_Capacity'][ind], data['Charge_Energy'][ind], data['Discharge_Energy'][ind], data['Cycle_Index'][ind])) #also add an if to filter only reset steps

    
#Reset Cycle Index so it can be fixed manually below
data.iloc[:, 5].apply(lambda x: zeroing(x), axis = 1)

#Subtract the values found in resetPoints from everything between the current point and the end of the array
for point in resetPoints:
    data.iloc[point[0]:, 5].apply(lambda x: x + 1)
    data.iloc[point[0]:, 8].apply(lambda x: x - point[2])
    data.iloc[point[0]:, 9].apply(lambda x: x - point[3])
    data.iloc[point[0]:, 10].apply(lambda x: x - point[4])
    data.iloc[point[0]:, 11].apply(lambda x: x - point[5])
```

Comment: One thing that I see is that the line `data.iloc[:, 5].apply(lambda x: zeroing(x), axis = 1)` is not doing anything, you'd have to assign it to a column, e.g., `data['new_column'] = data.iloc[:, 5].apply(lambda x: zeroing(x), axis = 1)`.

Comment: Another thing that might help for vectorizing your operations is [`pd.Series.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html).